# Studio not sending wpp messages with button

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I have a flow created using Studio and I'm trying to add buttons on my reply widgets but they're not including the buttons, this feature doesn't work with sandbox numbers?

I'm copying and pasting the same message as the approved template, the message comes, but without the button.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

approved_message = '...'

message = client.messages \
    .create(
         body=approved_message,
         from_='whatsapp:+15005550006',
         to='whatsapp:+14155238886'
     )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [Twilio WhatsApp sandbox only has three registered templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox#sandbox-templates) for testing and they do not have buttons. Those templates are:

> - Appointment Reminders: "Your appointment is coming up on {{1}} at {{2}}"
> - Order Notifications: "Your {{1}} order of {{2}} has shipped and should be delivered on {{3}}. Details: {{4}}"
> - Verification Codes: "Your {{1}} code is {{2}}"

When you have your own WhatsApp number you can [create your own templates that include buttons](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons), but it will not work with the sandbox.